# hide the delete button in a related list for a custom object

Tags: list, files

How can I hide the delete button for a record in a related list for that record's object?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the exact button you want to hide? My file related list does not have a delete button on it..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only see the delete option/button if you have the delete permission to the object shown in the list. If you remove the delete permission from the user profile/permission set they will not see the button anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think this functionality is still not implemented by salesforce yet, its still in idea exchange
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdnMkUAJ/enable-action-links-edit-del-to-be-hidden-on-listviews-and-related-lists

That being said, I think you can remove the delete permission from the profile like T_D_GP33 said and you can conditionally add that using permission set.
Here is one more useful link.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8MGaSAN

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.